# Using both String and Date on axis charts ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charts, ios-charts

I am using [Charts library by Daniel Gindi](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts/)

On the X axis of the line chart, I want to show 3 values (string, date, date). 
***1) Is it possible to format only one particular label into a string type value? 
2) Is it possible at all to show different value types on one axis?***

I've tried using a function `getFormattedLabel(index: Int)` but I haven't seen any examples of this function being used. Also, I can't find anything in documentation (it's for Android since there is no documentation for iOS): https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/

I want the axis to look like this: [Click here for the example of X axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4gIc.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a related question I asked with a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61009607/11219710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked one more question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62038981/11219710

It turned out, I needed to use this code in my `XAxisValueFormatter`:

```
if let index = axis?.entries.firstIndex(of: value), let count = axis?.entries.count  , index == count - 2 {
   return "Now"
}
```

It takes the index before the last one and returns a String type.