# How to set a custom x axis 0 label in charts ios

Tags: ios, swift, charts, axis-labels, ios-charts

I am using [Charts by Daniel Gindi](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

How can I set a String 0 label on x Axis? I want it to show "Now" instead of a Date type.
I've seen the function that helps to format one particular label only, but I can't get how it works. Moreover, I haven't seen any examples of it. So, how does `getFormattedLabel(index: Int)` work?
This is what I need my xAxis to look like:
[image: Example of what I need]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a snippet that helps me convert an X axis into timeline and also make the last label on the chart of a String type.

`index == count - 2` was used because the label count on X axis was set to 3 by force:

```
chart.xAxis.setLabelCount(3, force: true)
chart.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = false
chart.xAxis.forceLabelsEnabled = true
```

```
class ChartXAxisFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {

        if let index = axis?.entries.firstIndex(of: value), let count = axis?.entries.count  , index == count - 2 {
            return "Now"
        }

        let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value)
        let time = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)

            return time
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Chris! Thanks for your comment. I'm sorry I haven't posted any explanation - I wanted this solution to also be available for others struggling with the same question. I updated my comment and I hope it works now. I am actually the beginner in this community - I haven't asked much yet, so I'm still figuring things out. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can set your `xAxis.valueFormatter` to your own custom class and then return now when your x value is 0.
Like:

```
class ChartValueFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {

        if value == 0 {

            return "Now"
        }

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("dd MMM")
        dateFormatter.locale = .current

        let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value)

        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
}
```

For this to work you need to sort your values based on date and then set then now value timestamp to zero.

Answer (score 1):

It took a while to figure out, but I found [a great tutorial on Medium by Spencer Mandrusiak](https://medium.com/@spmandrus/ios-charts-custom-y-axis-values-e03cac8850c)

I needed to make the first label of a String type and all the others should still be Date types. 
What I did:

- Created an X axis formatting class.
- Added an enum with only one label
- When returning a value, I return time if there are no custom labels left.

This solution works well for me!

```
class ChartXAxisFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

    enum CustomLabel: Int {
        case firstLabel

        var label: String {
            switch self {
            case .firstLabel: return "Now"                
                }
            }
        }

 func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
            let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "hh:mm"

            let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value)
            let time = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)

            let intVal = Int(value)
            let customLabel = CustomLabel(rawValue: intVal)
            return customLabel?.label ?? "\(time)"


    }
}
```